# Is it ok to store a user id as the key of a field in a Firestore document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore charges for the amount of indexes used. If I have a structure where there is a massive list of ratings different users gave, and have the key as the user Id and the value as the rating, will that take up too many auto created indexes? Is there a good structure around this.

For example, in the collection 'ratings', I shard individual ratings that each user gives into different documents using a complex sharding mechanism I made that fills a document up to the max document size of around 20k, then starts filling up another document. say I have 5 documents, each filled with 20k fields. One of those docs would look like this:

```
uid1: 3.3
uid2: 5
uid3: 1.234
...
```

Is there another structure I should be using to store loads of individual 'fields' in Firestore? I don't want to use loads of documents for each rating either as that is too expensive. Arrays aren't big enough to store loads of ratings either.

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more clear about exactly what is the document structure for your collection?

Comment: sure! I updated the question

Comment: I've never heard of anyone trying to shard a collection by filling up documents one by one.  I'm not sure this is a recommended pattern, and it's not clear to me at all what the monetary saving is actually going to be either.  Firestore may not even be the best solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I mean it seems like a pretty common thing to want to be able to have a simple rating system in one's app. How do facebook store all the likes on a post - there can be millions. I already use mongodb due to firestores weak querying ability, I really would like to stick to firebase products for everything else.

Comment: @DougStevenson, in my use case I wanted an answer to his first query "... will that take up too many auto created indexes? " ... could you please answer that ? I am planning to make a small document (sharding not necessary) but many in number, and structured in a similar way of UID being the key ... { uid1 : data1, uid2, data2, ... }  and I am worried about costing for Indexes !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Arrays aren't big enough to store loads of ratings either

The problem isn't about the arrays, the problem is that the documents have limits. So there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas):

> Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. When we are talking about storing text, you can store pretty much but as your array getts bigger, be careful about this limitation.

According to the offical documentation regarding [modelling data in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model):

> Cloud Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents.

So trying to shard a collection by filling up documents one by one, is not such a good idea.

If you are trying to add raitings from multipe users in a single document, with other words you trying to store large amount of data in a single document that can be updated by lots of users, there is another limitation that you need to take care of. So you are limited to 1 write per second on every document. So if you have a situation in which a lot of users al all trying to write data to the same documents all at once, you might start to see some of this writes to fail. So, be careful about this limitation too.

My recommendation is to store those raitings in an array, if you think that the size of the document will be within the 1MiB limitation, otherwise use a collection of tags for each object separately.

Comment: hmm. I guess there really is no proper solution. To get around this, I'm going to put each rating as it's own separate document, then use a cloud function to map each document to a ratings array for each user, in mongo db. That way, I can read every single rating for a user and calculate the average solely on the server, then return just the average. Alse mongo have 16mb limit per doc, much much more ideal. should've just used mongodb in the first place ... :/ got scammed by the hype

Comment: MongoDb has its own benefits but I don't think there is something in MongoDb that cannot be achieved with Cloud Firestore but you can give it a try.

Comment: Sure. I cannot help but correct you. I have studied the in depth ins and outs of both firestore and mongo db, and it is with 100% certainty that the feature set mongodb has to offer is laughably more impressive than that of firestore. mongodb can be compared to SQL, while firestore can be compared to...well...i dunno what else is that limited for features....realtime database? The only advantages of using firestore is the speed, the ease of use and docs, and the integration with other amazing products like cloud functions, storage, etc.

Comment: @AlexMamo, in my use case I wanted an answer to his first query "... will that take up too many auto created indexes? " ... could you please answer that as well ? I am planning to make a small size document (sharding not necessary) that is structured in a similar way of UID being the key ... { uid1 : data1, uid2, data2, ... } and I am worried about costing for Indexes as the number of such documents is huge.

Comment: @kernelman Please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.